# Assigning a double to an integer in C causes the program to crash

Tags: c, integer, constants, double, undefined-behavior

I'm developing a visual application in C to render some firework explosions as a learning project. To control how fast they go up, I have a speed variable like this:

```
typedef struct Firework
{
    //Other data on the struct
    int speed;
} Firework;
```

I also needed to initialize the `speed` variable for every firework, so the next piece of code was this one:

```
// this works:
const int maxSpeed = 1;

// however if replaced with this, then the program will crash inside the loop
// const int maxSpeed = 0.5;

Firework fireworks[5] = { 0 };
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(fireworks) / sizeof(fireworks[0]); i++)
{
    fireworks[i].speed = (rand() % maxSpeed) + 1;
}
```

The problem is, I assigned the value `0.5` to `maxSpeed` by mistake and the result was program starting and then terminating almost immediately when I tried to use `maxSpeed`. I realized the mistake and fixed it but unfortunately I couldn't find much online and there are a few things I don't understand:

Is using a double to initialize an integer an undefined behaviour in C?

If so, why didn't I get any error or warning messages from my compiler? (Mingw-w64)

What was causing the application to terminate (sometimes even with an exit code of 0) instead of just behaving weirdly?

Did the `maxSpeed` variable being `const` had anything to do with this?

Comment: Assigning or initialing an integer variable with a floating point value *truncates* the value. So `0.5` becomes `0`. And division by `0` is never going to lead to nice stuff happening.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have no idea how I did not see that. Thank you very much :) Turns out I was going crazy for no reason...

Comment: The question is not useful by itself. The code that crashes is not presented in the question. You must use a debugger or other debugging methods to try and isolate the part of the code that **actually** crashes and present it in the question so that it truly contains a [mre].

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I actually have used a debugger and posted the code that causes the program to crash, it's the initialization of the Firework structure's speed variable: "...then terminating almost immediately when I tried to use maxSpeed".

Comment: Ah 0.5... i.e. I need to read the code more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0.5` converted to integer is ***`zero`***. Then you use the modulo `%` operator you divide the result of the `rand` function by zero - which of course will terminate the program on most hardware platforms. It is Undefined Behaviour.